# IOS13 Status Bar Background Color doesn't change to transparent after being set

Tags: swift, uiscrollview, uikit, statusbar, ios13

(IOS13) I am trying to implement the functionality that shows the navigation bar and status bar gradually after scrolling down the page (with the following code):

```
override func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    var offset = scrollView.contentOffset.y / 150
    print(offset)
    if offset > 1 { // show navigation bar

        offset = 1
        let color = UIColor.init(red: 1, green: 1, blue: 1, alpha: offset)

        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.barStyle = .default
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor(hue: 1, saturation: offset, brightness: 1, alpha: 1)
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.backgroundColor = color
        navigationController?.setStatusBar(backgroundColor: color)


    } else { // hide navigation bar

        let color = UIColor.init(red: 1, green: 1, blue: 1, alpha: offset)

        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor(hue: 1, saturation: offset, brightness: 1, alpha: 1)
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.backgroundColor = color
         navigationController?.setStatusBar(backgroundColor: color)

        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.barStyle = .black

    }
}
```

The navigation bar works perfectly. However, the status bar doesn't change back to the transparent color when I scroll back up. [Screenshots below]

[Initial State](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5FKlJ.png)

[Scroll A little bit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lBLhl.png)

[Scroll Back to initial State](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K3L4R.png)

I used this piece of code to update the status bar color:

```
extension UINavigationController {

func setStatusBar(backgroundColor: UIColor) {
    let statusBarFrame: CGRect
    if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
        statusBarFrame = view.window?.windowScene?.statusBarManager?.statusBarFrame ?? CGRect.zero
    } else {
        statusBarFrame = UIApplication.shared.statusBarFrame
    }
    let statusBarView = UIView(frame: statusBarFrame)
    statusBarView.backgroundColor = backgroundColor
    view.addSubview(statusBarView)
}
```

}